# UICollectionView in view controller

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I am looking for a possibility to drag and drop an image in a collection view cell to a UIImageView in the same view controller but outside of the collection view. The cv is below 5 collection views and i want to drag the image in the collection view and drop it into one of the 5 UIImage Views above the collection view. Is there a possibility to take the image from the collection view cell and reorder the collection view in new order so that the token dragged image (and cv-cell) will be deleted below? The images in the colectionview come from urls via json load. I am working with storyboard and with ARC ... 
Thanks a lot for any help or tipps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could load the images of the collection view inside an NSMutableArray, which you can run through in order to get the data your collection view must show. When you drag it from the collection view into the UIImageView, remove the correspondent index of that image inside the NSMutableArray and reload the collection view data. At the same time you get that image data and load it to the image view. This could help if I understood your problem.

Comment: thank you. i load the images from the database to an array at the moment. i have actually problems to implement my dragEnded method. i have to classes one class for the view controller and one class for the collevtionviewcell and there are 2 drag and drop methods one in each class. at the moment my uiimageview doesn't get the image i dragged in the collection view ... think the classes are not corresponding ... parameter stays null ... hmmm ...

Comment: - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{if ([touches count] == 1) {
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview.superview];
for (UIImageView *iView in self.subviews) {
if ([iView isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {if (touchPoint.x > iView.frame.origin.x && touchPoint.x < iView.frame.origin.x + iView.frame.size.width && touchPoint.y > iView.frame.origin.y && touchPoint.y < iView.frame.origin.y + iView.frame.size.height){self.dragObject = iView;
self.touchOffset = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x - iView.frame.origin.x,

Comment: touchPoint.y - iView.frame.origin.y);
self.homePosition = CGPointMake(iView.frame.origin.x, iView.frame.origin.y);}}}}}

Comment: - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    CGRect newDragObjectFrame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - _touchOffset.x,
                                           touchPoint.y - _touchOffset.y,
                                           self.frame.size.width,
                                           self.frame.size.height);
    self.frame = newDragObjectFrame;
    [self.superview.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
}

Comment: - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    FirstViewController *fvc = [FirstViewController new];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview.superview];
        fvc.mainImageview.image = self.dragObject.image;
        NSLog(@"mainImageviewimage%@",fvc.mainImageview.image);
   }